# How could I use VBA to change a button's picture to one of the embedded default images?

Tags: image, ms-access, button, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to get a button to change from the "Arrow Left" to "Arrow Right" picture when I click it, but I'm not sure how to assign the images through VBA. I tried `Me!btnCollapseUnscheduled.Picture = "Arrow Left"`, but I get an error message this way.

Comment: Is it simply one button on a form set to Single Form? Or is the button in the record of a form set to Continuous Forms? (I.e. it could appear multiple times and you want each button to be able to show a different image independently of ones in other records?)

Comment: It's just one button on one form, so no need for continuous form hocus pocus.

Comment: Do you want it to toggle back and forth between left and right arrows on each click?

Comment: Yeah, it's embedded right now. Using Access 2013. And yes, I'd like it to toggle.

Answer (score 6):

In Access 2010 or later, you can store images in the *MSysResources* system table.  Then choose *Shared* for your command button's *Picture Type* property, and select one of those shared images.

Afterward, it's easy to toggle between the shared images from the command buttons's click event.  I named my command button *"cmdArrow"* and the shared images *"Arrow Left"* and *"Arrow Right"* ...

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdArrow_Click()
    Dim strDirection As String

    If Me!cmdArrow.Picture Like "*Left" Then
        strDirection = "Right"
    Else
        strDirection = "Left"
    End If
    Me!cmdArrow.Picture = "Arrow " & strDirection
    Me!txtImage.Value = Me!cmdArrow.Picture
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me!txtImage.Value = Me!cmdArrow.Picture
End Sub
```

Screenshots:

[image: command button with Arrow Left image]

[image: command button with Arrow Right image]

The biggest challenge was loading the images into *MSysResources*.  I created a throwaway form and added a command button.  Next I chose *Embedded* as the button's *Picture Type* property and selected *Arrow Left* from the available choices.  Then I changed *Picture Type* from *Embedded* to *Shared*, which added a row to *MSysResources* with the image data in an attachment field and my command button's name in the *Name* field.  So I opened the table, changed *Name* to *"Arrow Left"* and closed the table.  Note *MSysResources* will not be visible in the Navigation pane unless you enable *"Show System Objects"* in the Navigation Options.

I repeated those steps for *"Arrow Right"*.  It may sound fiddly, but it's not really a huge hurdle.

Answer (score 3):

You could create two buttons where only one is visible at a time, both calling the same code.

When one is clicked, unhide the other, set focus to this, then hide the first button. And vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does this imply that it's impossible to programatically set the button image to one of the defaults?

Comment: Probably not, but it could take a while to find out, and it may very well only work when the form is in designview.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use the full file path of your icon.

MS-Access might be using some icon map for its native icons, so you might not have much luck getting a path to one of those.

If you definitely can't find the path to the native MS-Access icons, you could always just do a google image search for arrow icons (specify exact size of 16 x 16 pixels).

You can then just save these icons to a folder of your choosing and then use those paths in the following illustrations.

**If you just want the button to change its image on the first click and stay that way thereafter**:

1. Make sure the button does not have a picture attached in Design View.
2. Assign the default image using its full path to your command button using the form's Open event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Me.cmdButton.Picture = "C:\myFolder\myDefaultIcon.png"

End Sub
```

3. Then in the button's click event, assign the `.picture` property to the icon path you want to change it to:

```vb
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()

    Me.cmdButton.Picture = "C:\myFolder\myChangedIcon.png"

End Sub
```

**If you just want the button to toggle between 2 images on each click**:

1. Use a toggle button control instead of a command button control
2. Make sure the button does not have a picture attached in Design View.
3. Write a sub that will handle the different on/off states of your toggle button:

```vb
Public Sub togImg()

    If _
        Me.togButton = -1 _
    Then

        Me.togButton.Picture = "C:\myFolder\myChangedIcon.png"

    Else

        Me.togButton.Picture = "C:\myFolder\myDefaultIcon.png"

    End If

End Sub
```

4. Call your sub from both the form's Open event and the toggle button's Click event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    togImg

End Sub

Private Sub togButton_Click()

    togImg

End Sub
```