# How to change an embedded image on a command button?

Tags: vba, image, ms-access

I have a button with an image on it. It's an embedded picture taken from the picture property in the Picture Builder dialog. The image is named "Sort Descending" in the Picture Builder dialog.

When the form loads, the sort is Ascending on the field. When the user clicks on the button, the recordset is sorted Descending.

I need to change the image programmatically to the "Sort Ascending" image that is in the Picture Builder dialog.

I'm thinking it's in one of the system databases.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the button that you have currently and the sketch of the button you want to show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I use VBA to change a button's picture to one of the embedded default images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357544/how-could-i-use-vba-to-change-a-buttons-picture-to-one-of-the-embedded-default)

Comment: Might also find this of interest https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/734893-where-access-icons-located

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable and change its value each time the user clicks the button. Then change the picture based on the value

Something like:-

In a module:

```
Option Explicit

Global booSorted As Boolean
```

Then in the button onClick event

```
Private Sub cmdBtnName_Click()

If booSorted=True then

booSorted=False
Me.cmdBtnName.Picture = "ImagePath1"

Else

booSorted=True
Me.cmdBtnName.Picture = "ImagePath2"

End if

End Sub
```

Comment: There was a link above with exactly what I was looking for and that would be to add the embedded image to MSysResources. Unfortunately, from what I understand from the post, only 2010 or later will do that. Even though I'm on 2013 (and still don't see the MSysRecources table) I'm writing for 2007.